# is it possible to solve this error which appeared after I updated my Mac?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

That's the error, and I don't know how to solve it. Would you please help me? I have to complete a project for college.

```
//
[{
    "resource": "/Users/lll/C++/Functions/decimal_to_octal.cpp",
    "owner": "C/C++",
    "code": "1696",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (/Users/tarang/C++/Functions/decimal_to_octal.cpp).",
    "source": "C/C++",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 20
}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre], and [edit] your question to show it (together with a copy-paste of the actual build errors you get, if any).

Comment: Run Xcode at least once to accept license agreement, without it tool chain is not available. Or just run `sudo xcodebuild -license accept`.

Comment: I am using vs code, and that's the error     #include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled

Comment: Refer to [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac#_cc-configuration) to config the C/C++ extension, especially the "Include path" setting.